# how to pass in paramters to a post request using the servicestack json client

Tags: servicestack

I'm having trouble getting my servicestack json client to format a REST Post request.

I'm trying to post to my login service with a raw json body of

```
{"Uname":"joe", "Password":"test"}
```

but the post methods is actually mistakenly sending this

```
{"login":""}
```

Here's the code I'm using.

```
    JsonServiceClient.HttpWebRequestFilter = filter =>
        {
            filter.Headers.Add(string.Format("X-API-Key: {0}", "test"));
        };

   var client = new JsonServiceClient(url);
   var url = "/login";
   var login = new LoginModel { Uname = uname, Password = pwd };
   return client.Post<UserCredentials>(url, login);
```

How should I structure the parameter object so that it serializes to the correctly to the intended raw value in the post request? Additionally, can I just pass in a dictionary or a more generic object so that I don't have to create a LoginModel class or struct?

Comment: You should post what the full exception is (preferably the HTTP Response dump that you can get from Fiddler or WireShark). You also want to add the signature outline of the Service you're trying to call as well as the Routes defined so we can see if you've created it properly or not.

Comment: Have you tried to write (url, login.toJSON())

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was that I was using public fields instead of public properties in my LoginModel.  Changing it to properties fixed it.